# Jsch: Get the number of open channels of a session

Tags: java, jsch

Is there any way to get the number of open channels on a Jsch `session`? I'm trying to setup a session cache that auto disconnects sessions if there are no active/open channels on the session, is that possible?

Comment: There's no such API. The channels are stored in global `Channel.pool` vector and it's not publicly accessible.

Comment: Damn. Is there any way to tell if there is any activity on the session? Or is there a better way to cache sessions?